# Translating Insert into select to Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to create multiple sequential number series
The serial number would look like -
e.g.

> M1-00000001 M2-00000001 M1-00000002 M3-00000001
>   M2-00000002 ...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SerialNumber](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MachineId] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Snr] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SerialNumber] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I then use this query to create a new serial number

```
DECLARE @machine_id AS NCHAR(10)
SET @machine_id = 'M2'
INSERT INTO SerialNumber (MachineId,Snr)

SELECT @machine_id ,IIF(MAX(Snr) is not null,MAX(SNR)+1,1)
from SerialNumber
where MachineId=@machine_id
```

How would I do this in Entity Framework 6.1.3?

EDIT: I rewrote the whole question, don't know it you are suppose to do that, but someone will probably tell me if it's considered bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited after comments:
This requires `DbContext` to be properly set up with a `SerialNumbers` property that represents the SerialNumber table. The `SerialNumber` objects are represented by the following class:

```
public class SerialNumber
{
    public int Id {get;set;} //Added after edit
    public string MachineId {get;set;}
    public int Snr {get;set;} //I assume it is a nullable int
}
```

and then some code similar to this should do the job:

```
public void AddSerial(string machineId)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        int max = context.SerialNumbers
            .Where(sn => sn.MachineId  == machineId)
            .Select(sn => sn.Snr)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
            .Max(); //Extra clauses added after edit
        max++;
        context.SerialNumbers.Add(new SerialNumber{ MachineId = machineId, Snr = max});
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't take MachineId in consideration when getting the Max(Snr) does it? there are one serie per MachineId.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that there is one SerialNumber per MachineId? If so what is the meaning of MAX? The code I posted retrieves the max Snr of all SerialNumber entries in the db regardless of MachineId.

Comment: I have edited the question, but Yes there is one serial number series per machine and I need to get the max for that serie.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework in an ORM, so you must create an object and link to your database, as follow:

You must:

- have a class named `SerialNumber`
- map with underlyng database table
- persist your object in a `DBContext`

[**Here**](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx) you can find a guide to use Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the following error: The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null

I changed GDS' code to the following to handle when the select finds 0 rows and returns a null value.

```
public void AddSerial(string machineId)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        int max = context.SerialNumbers
            .Where(sn => sn.MachineId  == machineId)
            .Max(sn =>(int?)sn.Snr) ?? 0; //Extra clauses added after edit
        max++;
        context.SerialNumbers.Add(new SerialNumber{ MachineId = machineId, Snr = max});
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```